# _В размере пяти миллионов рублей_ или _В размере пять миллионов рублей_

Tags: управление

*В размере пяти миллионов рублей* или *В размере пять миллионов рублей*.

Как правильно?

Answer (score 2):

**В размере (чего?) пяти миллионов**. Родительный падеж.
Вариант именительного появился видимо под влиянием использования всякого рода бланков и заготовок, куда вписывалась только сумма. Ну и первые компьютерные программы, не умевшие склонять числа, добавили путаницы. Но норма-то осталась.

Толкование "в варианте (каком?)" здесь не проходит, каком - это все равно не именительный, а предложный.